# How to get and replace the word on the left of the cursor

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

For a word add-ins in javascript, a simple use case is to get the word on the left of the cursor and to replace it in upper case.

For example, if `|` is the cursor:

- `Hello world|` will become `Hello WORLD|`
- `Hello| world` will become `HELLO| world`

Is it possible to perform this example with the [Word.Range class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.range?view=word-js-preview)? For example, to expand the range until a space like this fictive code:

```js
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var selection = context.document.getSelection();
        var cursor = selection.getRange('Start');

        // Fictive: how to expand the range to the left until a space?
        var range = cursor.expandToLeftUntil(' ');
        range.load("text");
        var html = range.getHtml();
        await context.sync();
        var textToReplace = html.value.toUpperCase();


        // Replace the text
        range.insertText(textToReplace, 'Replace');
        await context.sync();
    });
```

Or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

A possible strategy is to use the [search method](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/word/search-option-guidance) to get a RangeCollection of all the words in the document (or body or paragraph, etc.). Then get a reference to the current selected range (where the cursor is). Then loop through the collection and call the [Range.compareLocationWith](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/word/word.range#word-word-range-comparelocationwith-member(1)) method to find the range that is "AdjacentBefore" the currently selected range.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do a similar thing. At least, when a selection is empty get the word nearby the cursor. I hope their would be some API function, but that's not the case.

I started out with the answer/idea of Rick Kirkham (thanks!). I couldn't get to search method to work to get a list of words. Using split on a space worked fine though.

Instead of select like I do you could modify the the text.
If you don't want to get close-by but only after you should alter the function to check `'InsideStart'` (in that scenario you would like to go to the previous word, so `i-1`).

```
Word.run(async (context) => {

    let cursorOrSelection = context.document.getSelection();
    cursorOrSelection.load();
    
    await context.sync();

    // if the cursor is empty we make a selection of the Word close-by
    // this behaviour is done automatically when you insert a comment in Word
    if (cursorOrSelection.isEmpty) {
        
        console.log("Empty selection, cursor.");
        
        // get the paragraph closest to the cursor. 
        const paragraph = cursorOrSelection.paragraphs.getFirst(); 
        const allWordsInParagraph = paragraph.split([" "], true /* trimDelimiters*/, true /* trimSpaces */);
        
        allWordsInParagraph.load();
        
        await context.sync();

        // compare the cursorRange with the ranges of individual words in the paragraph. 
        let compareRanges = [];
        
        allWordsInParagraph.items.forEach( item => {
            compareRanges.push({
                compare: cursorOrSelection.compareLocationWith(item),
                range: item
            });
        });

        await context.sync();

        // walk through all the words and compare the location relation with the cursor
        // were the location relation changes, the word is near the cursor.

        let previousLocationRelation = null;
        let wordClosestToCursorRange = null;

        for (let i = 0; i < compareRanges.length; i++) {
            const locationRelation = compareRanges[i].compare.value;
            
            console.log(locationRelation);

            // if first entry is Before, we are at the beginning
            if(i==0 && locationRelation === 'Before') {
                wordClosestToCursorRange = compareRanges[i].range;

                // jump out
                break;
            } 
            else {

                if(previousLocationRelation && locationRelation != previousLocationRelation) {
                    // first "edge" we find. 
                    // console.log('-- edge');
                    
                    // if first edge we encounter is Before
                    // we need the previous one (could be after)
                    if(locationRelation === 'Before') {
                        wordClosestToCursorRange = compareRanges[i-1].range;
                    }
                    else {
                        // we are inside the word or end of the word
                        // Inside, InsideStart, InsideEnd
                        wordClosestToCursorRange = compareRanges[i].range;
                    }

                    // jump out we are only interested in the first edge
                    break;
                }

            }

            previousLocationRelation = locationRelation;
            
        }

        wordClosestToCursorRange.select();
    }

    return context.sync();
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
})
```